# NSString property making a shallow copy

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I am having some trouble understanding what is going on with these two string properties declared in separate classes:

`@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *userPhone;`

and

`@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *userLogin;`

Somewhere in the code I go and do the following:

`user.userPhone = self.userLogin;`

What I would expect is that `userLogin` gets copied into a new object and assigned to `userPhone`. However, I found out that they both share a reference to the same object! So when `userLogin` get released, so does `userPhone`, breaking my poor app.

I know that I am missing something about memory management here, but I don't understand why `copy` does not work in this case.

Anyone knows?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did `@synthesize` or `@dynamic`, if you `@synthesize` did you override the setter?

Comment: This should be another object... Don't you have a userPhone = self.userLogin somewhere else ?

Comment: Yeah I did `@synthesize` and I did not override the setter

Comment: @Rabskatran Nop I checked at that very line and copy made both point to the same object

Comment: The optimization in NSString's `copy` should not break your program. If it is, something is wrong with your program.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NSString` objects **are immutable**, meaning that their contents can not change once they have been created. To exploit this, the `copy` method does not create a new string. Instead, it retains the original string*. This is an internal optimization, from your point of view **standard memory management rules apply.** If you have problems with the string being `dealloc`ated before you expect, you must be over-releasing it somewhere else.

`stringWithString:` is also internally optimized in the same manner. If you pass an immutable string as the argument, it will not create a new one*. If you execute the following code, you will see that string1 and string2 addresses are the same.

```
NSString *string1 = @"Test";
NSString *string2 = [NSString stringWithString:string1];
NSLog(@"%p, %p",string1, string2);
```

(*) *These are implementation details that are subject to change at any time.*

Comment: even if were using NSMutableString instead of NSString, the method "stringWithString:" will still result in a shallow copy?

Comment: @hemant no, if you call `[NSString stringWithString:mutableString]` or `[NSMutableString stringWithString:immutableString]`, it will create a new string.

Answer (score -1):

You may be double releasing the original. If i remember the copy property will actually just retain an immutable copy (i.e NSString) and only do a hard copy if it is mutable (NSMutableString). Its possible the original string is autoreleased and you give it a hard release, accounting for two decrements.
Edit:

After reading other posts i have changed mine to reflect.

Comment: Thanks but I would like to know why `copy` did not work as expected.

Comment: You may be double releasing the original.  If i remember the copy property will actually just retain an immutable copy (i.e NSString) and only do a hard copy if it is mutable (NSMutableString).  So if you need a guaranteed hard copy of an immutable string you may have to use stringWithString

Comment: `stringWithString:` is also optimized internally to exploit the fact that `NSString`s are immutable and it will return the same object passed as argument (as long as it is immutable).

Comment: As albertamg said, this doesn't guarantee an actual separate instance any more than `copy` does. And it shouldn't matter.